# Type Conversion from SPlist item to String list

Tags: list

```
     public static IEnumerable<string> GetAllStreams()
                {       
                    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("`http://abzv67`"))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("/"))
                        {
                            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                            query.Query = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Code' /></Eq></Where></Query>"; 
                            string listUrl = "/Lists/Work Streams";
                            var list = web.GetList(listUrl);                    
                            return list.GetItems(query).Cast<string>();
                        }
                    }
                }

public static IEnumerable<string> GetAllDocs()
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://abzv67"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("/"))
                {
                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                    query.Query = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Code' /></Eq></Where></Query>"; 
                    string listUrl = "/Lists/Document Types";
                    var list = web.GetList(listUrl);
                    return list.GetItems(query).Cast<string>(); 
                }
            }
        }
```

I have the following method and I am trying to call this method as

```
List<string> codes = GetAllStreams().ToList();
```

I am getting the error as

```
"Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem' to type 'System.String'."
```

How do I fix this ?

My Actual intention is to get the cartesian product of the two sp lists. Hence, I have written the  following method.

```
public static IEnumerable<List<string>> GetCombinations(IEnumerable<List<string>> lists, IEnumerable<string> selected)
        {
            if (lists.Any())
            {
                var remainingLists = lists.Skip(1);
                foreach (var item in lists.First().Where(x => !selected.Contains(x)))
                foreach (var combo in GetCombinations(remainingLists, selected.Concat(new string[] { item })))
                yield return combo;
            }
            else
            {
                yield return selected.ToList();
            }
        }
```

I am using this method in my Web part (sandboxed) aimed to host on Office 365.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> codes = CombineLists.GetAllStreams().ToList();
            List<string> docs = CombineLists.GetAllDocs().ToList();
            List<List<string>> lists = new List<List<string>> { codes, docs };
            var combos = CombineLists.GetCombinations(lists, new List<string>()).Distinct();
            foreach (var combo in combos)
                msgLabel.Text = string.Join("-", combo.Select(x => x.ToString()));
            msgLabel.Visible = true;
            return;
        }
```

My Aim is to get all the possible combinations of the list items in two lists. One list is in this format.

("00.0","01.0","02.0","03.0","04.0","04.1","04.2","04.3","04.4","04.5","05.0","05.1","05.2","06.0","07.0","08.0","09.0","10.0","10.1","10.2","10.3","10.4","10.5","11.0","11.1","11.2","11.3","11.4","12.0","12.1","12.2","13.0","14.0","15.0","16.0","17.0","18.0","18.1","19.0","20.0","21.0","21.1","21.2","21.3","22.0","23.1","23.2","23.3","23.4","23.5","24.0","24.1","24.2","25.0","25.1","25.2","26.1","26.2","26.3","26.4","26.5","27.1","27.2","27.3","27.4","28.1","28.2","29.1","29.2","30.1","30.2","30.3","30.4","30.5","31.0")

Other list is in this format.

("PL","PR","FO","CE","OC","JD","TD","LD")

I need the final string of all the possible combination as (00.0-PL) and add them in another list.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you trying to convert full list items to a single string?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to convert them as string list

Comment: The main question was why you triy to do this:)

Comment: Trying to get the combination of Two lists as Cartesian Product.

Comment: public static IEnumerable<List<string>> GetCombinations(IEnumerable<List<string>> lists, IEnumerable<string> selected)
        {
            if (lists.Any())
            {
                var remainingLists = lists.Skip(1);
                foreach (var item in lists.First().Where(x => !selected.Contains(x)))
                foreach (var combo in GetCombinations(remainingLists, selected.Concat(new string[] { item })))
                yield return combo;
            }
            else
            {
                yield return selected.ToList();
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

Take list items in datatable or splistitemcollections and then merge another list with datatable.

You can use:

```
DataTable dt = oList.Items.GetDataTable();
```

or

```
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(spq); 
DataTable dt = items.GetDataTable();
```

Comment: Please add more details regarding how to do what you propose. Right now your answer is not as helpful as it could be :)

Comment: DataTable dt = oList.Items.GetDataTable(); or SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(spq);
dtItems = items.GetDataTable();

Comment: Updated your answer with that info :)

Comment: Dear Robert, I have updated the whole request again. Hope that make sense. Please help me.

Comment: Could some one help me with this please?